# Extract filename from file using shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, aix

I have a text file which has the following line:

```
/u/tux/abc/spool/frtbla_mcdetc_0000149099_20101126135009990_1.tif
```

I want to extract `frtbla_mcdetc_0000149099_20101126135009990_1.tif`;
the word after the last slash (`/`).

Comment: if you are open to using excel - you easily accomplish this - "without VB script"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a Linux-like environment you can use the `basename` utility:

```
basename $(<your_file)
```

Comment: thanks.. i came up with the method..firstly i removed all "/" than used the last parameter..but your's is the best..

Answer (score 0):

use this command

```
cat text_file_name | cut -d '/' -f 6
```

Comment: Looks like we both answered at the same time! Just for your own edification, cut operates on files directly. Often simply `cat`ing a file falls under what's known - somewhat judgementally - as a "[useless use of `cat`](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html)"; unless you are viewing the file or similar (though there again you could use `less`)

Comment: @bertieb appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact format of the directory structure and it won't alter, you can use `cut`:

```
$ cut -f6 -d '/' file.txt
```

Here uses cut to treat the directory separators as a delimiter and extract the 6th one.

If instead all you know is it is the **last part of a line but don't know the directory structure**, you can use `rev` as well:

```
$ rev file.txt | cut -f1 -d '/' | rev
```

Here the file is reversed and the **first** field is extracted, before being reversed again.

Answer (score 0):

The following applies to **all** strings in a shell, not just filenames, and is far easier than cut because you don't need to know how many fields there are before the one you want:

```
$ foo=/path/to/file/split/by/slashes.txt
$ echo ${foo##*/}
slashes.txt
```

This uses the 'greedy trim', i.e. trim everything until the last '/' as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162385/how-to-split-a-string-in-shell-and-get-the-last-field

```
${foo  <-- from variable foo
  ##   <-- greedy front trim
  *    <-- matches anything
  /    <-- until the last '/'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the standard shell is in Aix, but `bash` is available and supports edited expansion of variables.

If your full name is in the variable `FileName`, then `${FileName##*/}` displays the name with all leading characters deleted as far as the last `/`; by contrast `${FileName#*/}` deletes up to the first `/`, while `${FileName%/*}` deletes trailing characters from the last `/` (ie the directory path).

If you generate the file name(s) by a `find` command, then you need a command like:

```
find ... | while read FileName; do echo ${FileName##*/}; done
```

If in a text file:

```
while read FileName; do echo ${FileName##*/}; done < FileList.txt
```

Replace the `echo` command by whatever processing you need to do with the name.

Comment: (I seem to have crossed with other answers, but I'll let my answer stand, as parts of it are not covered elsewhere.)